# Hangman java coding

Tags: java

I have two problems with this code. I need to display _ _ _ _ _ for the word "boats" as the user guesses letters. The underspaces need to be replaced with the guessed letters as the user inputs them. 
Also I have a counter to keep track of the good guesses, which should end the game after 5 guesses, but that doesn't happen when I run the code. Any suggestions on either problem?

```
    private static String [] word = {"b","o", "a","t","s"}; // array to hold the secret word
    private static boolean finished = false;    // boolean flag to control the main loop
    private static int badGuesses = 0;          // int variable to hold the number of incorrect guesses
    private static ArrayList<String> guessedLetters = new ArrayList<String>();      // String array to mark which letters have been guessed
    private static String entryWord = " ";          // string variable for the user's guesses
    private static int goodGuesses = 0;             // int variable to hold the number of correct guesses
    private static String guess;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    playGame ();

}


public static void playGame ()
{
    displayRules(); // print the instructions to the user

    while (!finished)

    {
        String guess =  getGuess(); // allow user to input a guess
        checkGuess(word, guess); // identify user's guess as correct or incorrect
        showWord (); // print the underscores representing the word
        showMan(); // print the appropriate hanging man
    }

    while (goodGuesses == 5)
        winGame();
}

public static void displayRules()       // display the rules to the user
{
    String userName;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Please enter your name.");
    userName = keyboard.next(); 


    System.out.println ("Hello " + userName + "!");
    System.out.println ("Welcome to Dan's Hangman game!");
    System.out.println ("The objective of the game is to guess all of the letters of the secret word");
    System.out.println ("The user will guess a letter and if it is correct, the user has won that round.");
    System.out.println ("If the user guesses an incorrect letter, the user will gain a strike.");
    System.out.println ("A strike will cause part of the man to be hanged");
    System.out.println ("The game will end after the user either gets 6 strikes, or guesses the entire word correctly.");
    System.out.println ("----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" ");
}


public static void showMan()            // display the appropriate hanging man based on the number of incorrect guesses
{
    if (badGuesses==0)
        man_0();
    else if (badGuesses==1)
        man_1();
    else if(badGuesses==2)
        man_2();
    else if(badGuesses==3)
        man_3();
    else if(badGuesses==4)
        man_4();
    else if(badGuesses==5)
        man_5();
    else if (badGuesses==6)
        man_6();


}

public static void showWord ()      // Show the status of the word as it is guessed
{



    String s = word.toString();
    char [] showWordArray = s.toCharArray();
    char c = guess.charAt(0);
     boolean contains = true; // boolean flag to control the loop

    for (int i=0; i<word[0].length(); i++)
    {
        //showWordArray[i] += '_';

        if (showWordArray[i] == c)
        {   
            System.out.print (c);
        }
        else
            System.out.print ('_');
    }

    System.out.println (" ");
}





public static String getGuess()         // allow the user to guess a letter
{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("  ");
    System.out.println ("Please enter a guess");
    guess = keyboard.nextLine();
    return guess;
}

public static String checkGuess (String [] word, String guess)  // identify if the user's guess if correct or incorrect
{

    int index = 0;      // loop control variable
    int element= -1;    // element the string is found at
    boolean found= false;   // flag indicating search results


    do
    {
        if (word[index].equals(guess))
            {
                System.out.println ("You guessed correctly!");
                goodGuesses++;
                found = true;

            }
        index++;

    }
    while (index< word.length);

    if (found == false) 
    {
        System.out.println ("Sorry, you guessed incorrectly ");
        badGuesses ++;
    }           

return Integer.toString (element);

}

public static void loseGame ()
{
    if (badGuesses == 6)
        System.out.println ("Sorry, you lost! :(");
        finished = true;
}

public static void winGame()
{
    if (goodGuesses == 5)
        System.out.println ("Congratulations! You have won!");
        finished = true;
}


public static void man_0()
{
    System.out.println ("_____");
    System.out.println ("|   |");
    System.out.println ("|");
    System.out.println ("|");
    System.out.println ("|");

    System.out.println ("You have 6 guesses left");
}

public static void man_1()
{
    System.out.println ("_____");
    System.out.println ("|   |");
    System.out.println ("|   o");
    System.out.println ("|");
    System.out.println ("|");

    System.out.println ("You have 5 guesses left");
}

public static void man_2()
{
    System.out.println ("_____");
    System.out.println ("|   |");
    System.out.println ("|   o");
    System.out.println ("|   |");
    System.out.println ("|");

    System.out.println ("You have 4 guesses left");
}

public static void man_3()
{
    System.out.println ("_____");
    System.out.println ("|   |");
    System.out.println ("|   o");
    System.out.println ("|  /|");
    System.out.println ("|");

    System.out.println ("You have 3 guesses left");
}

public static void man_4()
{

    System.out.println ("_____");
    System.out.println ("|   |");
    System.out.println ("|   o");
    System.out.println ("|  /|\\");
    System.out.println ("|");

    System.out.println ("You have 2 guesses left");
}

public static void man_5()
{
    System.out.println ("_____");
    System.out.println ("|   |");
    System.out.println ("|   o");
    System.out.println ("|  /|\\");
    System.out.println ("|  /");

    System.out.println ("You have 1 guess left");
}

public static void man_6()
{
    System.out.println ("_____");
    System.out.println ("|   |");
    System.out.println ("|   o");
    System.out.println ("|  /|\\");
    System.out.println ("|  / \\");
    loseGame();
}
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you tell us specifically what currently happens, what you want to happen, and any results of your debugging so far.

Comment: It displays if the guess is correct or incorrect, and displays one underscore to represent the word. I've tried using array lists to keep track of the correct guesses and converting the letters in the 'word' array to a char array and searching through that array. Neither have worked for me

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's causing your problem (@JeffreyBosboom's suggestions would certainly help) but I can see a few places where the code could be written better. `found == false` should be `!found`, the `if`-`else` chain in showMan() would be better as a `switch` statement, and all those `man` functions could just be one function that takes the number of wrong guesses as an argument.

Comment: Here's something else I've tried in my showWord method          for (int i =0; i<word.length; i++)
  {
   if (word[i].equals(guess))
    System.out.print (word[i]);
    
   else
    System.out.print ('_');
  }
  
  System.out.println (" ");
 }

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the logic of your `showWord` method is wrong.  But rather than correcting it for you I'm just going to give you a HINT ... in the form of a question.

- Where does your code test the 2nd character of the "guess"?

---

The other thing to note is that your representation of `word` as an array of `String` objects is "unnatural".  The natural representation is `String`, with `char[]` being a possible alternative.

I mention this primarily because your current choice of representation is making your code more convoluted than it needs to be.

Comment: I changed the method to be this now

for (int i =0; i<word.length; i++)
{
     if (word[i].equals(guess))
 System.out.print (word[i]);
    
 else
    System.out.print ('_');
  }
  
  System.out.println (" ");
 }

When a correct letter is guessed, this prints it out at the right location. i.e. if you guess 'a', it prints _ _ a _ _. 
But if another correct letter is guessed, say b, it only prints
b _ _ _ _. Eventhough two correct letters have been guessed.

Does this make more sense?

Comment: Yes.  That makes sense.  You need to think some more about the logic of your code.